# What app allows me to block "probable" spam calls

Tags: calls, call-screening, spam

I receive 2 or 3 calls per day from random spammers. I have tried blocking the numbers, but it is no use as they just call with new numbers. Is there anyway to avoid this? I suppose the end solution could be changing my number with a new sim card.

I have tried the app MrNumber, and I have tried a few other apps, but they all suffer from the problem of only blocking single numbers. Spam callers have too many number to utilize. Are there any apps that come with an extensive black list pre-installed? Or some method of detecting what other people have marked as spam?

Comment: FYI: We find it's better to describe the problem you're trying to solve rather than asking us to help you find an app.

Comment: Enable your call blocklist and use whitelist method (block call from strangers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend just recommended [Call Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flexaspect.android.everycallcontrol&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) to me for this very reason. I'm starting to get spam calls on my cell phone and it disgusts me. Plus there's a black list feature as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try True caller, it comes up with the preloaded blacklist and spammer numbers and keeps on updating..it has some interersting features too..

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Your answer would be more valuable if you included a link to the app.